# I would like to embed UINavigationController with UITableViewController which is the sub-view of UITabBarViewController by programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Recently, I want to make an App for self-study and that App looks like **Contacts** App in iOS.  First, I have two UITableViewControllers connecting to UITabBarViewController. Then I want to embed UINavigationController with those 2 tableviews by coding (In this case, I don't want to embed it in Storyboard by design). But I'm stuck with it. Here is my code in **AppDelegate**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let tabBar : UITabBarViewController = UITabBarViewController()
    let tableView1 : UITableViewController = UITableViewController()
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableView1)
    let tableView2 : UITableViewController = UITableViewController()
    let nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableView2)
    tabBar.viewControllers = [nav, nav2]
    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBar

    return true
}
```

And the result always displays the first **tableView1**. How can I make it to display two tab options(on the bottom of the view) in UITabBarViewController? If I make it by designing in Storyboard, I'm sure it will work fine. But by coding, I've no idea how to fix it.
Please kindly guide me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please update your code to be runnable. Where `mainView` came from?. Not `UITabBarViewController`, but `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Hi Rintaro,
Thanks for reviewing my code. It's typo issue. **mainView** should be *tabBar** which is the object of UITabBarViewController. And it is the main view of the other 2 UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `UITabBarViewController` in UIKit. It is called `UITabBarController`. Your ViewControllers need to have NavigationItems. If you display them like in your code you will have a Tabbar on bottom but without anything visible on it. In your case the NavigationControllers are the ones where you need to define nav.navigationItem.title = ...

EDIT:
and I realized you are not initializing the window. This is not related to your other problem but you would not see anything with your code. So you have to change it to:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds);
self.window?.rootViewController = tabBar
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
```

Comment: Thank with your answer but no luck for me.

Comment: why, when I run your code and exchange the line with the above it shows the controllers as expected?

Comment: When I run, it will display one tableview but it does not show the title however I set the title of those 2 tableviews already. I'm totally new with Swift so I really have no idea about it.